# Accessibility service notification removed

Tags: android, service, notifications, accessibility, accessibilityservice

Is there anyway to know what notification have been removed? When I call this code:

```
@Override
public void onServiceConnected() {
    AccessibilityServiceInfo info = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();
    info.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPES_ALL_MASK;
    info.notificationTimeout = 1;
    info.feedbackType = AccessibilityEvent.TYPES_ALL_MASK;
    setServiceInfo(info);
}

@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
    String s = event.getText()+"";
    Log.d(TAG, s);
}
```

I only got `Notification dissmised`, but this don't tell me which notification was dismissed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You should use [NotificationListenerService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html) for this purpose (To catch Notification of application [NotificationListenerService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html) is another option like Accessibility Service).*

Where [onNotificationRemoved](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html#onNotificationRemoved%28android.service.notification.StatusBarNotification%29) gives [StatusBarNotification](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/StatusBarNotification.html) into parameter. By reading this param you can get all information about notification.

You can read [NotificationListenerService-Example](https://github.com/kpbird/NotificationListenerService-Example) for more details.

Comment: I have no idea about this if there any option available or not. If you will get update this answer :).

Comment: http://gmariotti.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/how-to-write-dashclock-extension_23.html?m=1 read this if can help?

Comment: After reading that link I implemented something very similar.

Comment: Could you please provide your answer here? I can't seem to find anything on that blog that will solve this, it only uses the screen on/off which will not work for many apps. How do you even get "Notification dissmised" event when the notification has been removed in the first place? Maybe post the answer?